# In Python, how to you check to see if a list of items is exclusive to one list out of two?

Tags: python, list, contains

I have two lists that contain mutually exclusive items - let's pick oil and water based liquids for these lists since these naturally can't mix:

```
waters = ['tea', 'lemonade', 'juice', 'pepsi']
oils = ['olive oil', 'corn oil', 'peanut oil']
```

I want to test if foo only contains items in the water list or the oils list but NOT both. such that:

```
foo = ['tea', 'corn oil'] => FAIL
bar = ['pepsi', 'tea', 'juice'] => PASS
baz = ['olive oil'] => PASS
```

my attempt so far:

```
def contains_conflicting_types(test, targets, conflicts):
    intarget = False
    inconflict = False
    for t in test:
        if t in targets:
            intarget = True
        if t in conflicts:
            inconflict = True
        if intarget and inconflict:
            return True
    return False

#Usage:
contains_conflicting_types(['A','B'], ['A','1'], ['B','2']) #returns True A and B are in conflict
```

needless to say it's ugly but works?  how can I do it better?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where would vinaigrette go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define everything as sets (or convert them to sets) and then it's straightforward set/bitwise ops:

```
bool(oils & foo) ^ bool(waters & foo)
Out[19]: False

bool(oils & bar) ^ bool(waters & bar)
Out[20]: True

bool(oils & baz) ^ bool(waters & baz)
Out[21]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick one-liner might look like:

```
def contains_conflicting_types(test, targets, conflicts):
    return not(all(t in targets for t in test) or all(t in conflicts for t in test))
```

This would be faster if `targets` and `conflicts` were sets, since in that case the `in` operator would work in constant time. If you can't make the inputs sets, then you can write:

```
def contains_conflicting_types(test, targets, conflicts):
    targets, conflicts = set(targets), set(conflicts)
    return not(all(t in targets for t in test) or all(t in conflicts for t in test))
```

If `test` is also a set, then you can take advantage of the overloaded `<=` operator that does subset checks and write:

```
def contains_conflicting_types(test, targets, conflicts):
    return not (test <= targets or test <= conflicts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the two sets to compare against

```
waters = frozenset(['tea', 'lemonade', 'juice', 'pepsi'])
oils = frozenset(['olive oil', 'corn oil', 'peanut oil'])
```

And a test group

```
foo = frozenset(['tea', 'corn oil'])
```

You can determine if the set contains items from exclusively one group (using the [XOR](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) operator) by checking if the sets are [disjoint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) (two sets are disjoint if their intersection is the empty set).

```
foo.isdisjoint(waters) ^ foo.isdisjoint(oils)
```

For Python 2.5 and older, use:

```
bool(foo.intersection(waters)) ^ bool(foo.intersection(oils))
```

Alternatively, if you can remember that `&` is the intersection operator when acting on two sets. Because readability counts, if you or other people who are (or will be) maintaining your code aren't sure what the `&` character means without looking it up, just use `s1.intersection(s2)`.

```
bool(foo & waters) ^ bool(foo & oils)
```